# django1.9 - Makemigration Error: app label has extra "dot"

Tags: django

I tried to group serveral apps into a "app" folder for better management. however i got the below error when i did the first migration.

```
./manage.py makemigrations

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 132, in handle
    migration_name=self.migration_name,
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 45, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 128, in _detect_changes
    self.old_apps = self.from_state.concrete_apps
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 166, in concrete_apps
    self.apps = StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models, ignore_swappable=True)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 228, in __init__
    self.render_multiple(list(models.values()) + self.real_models)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 296, in render_multiple
    model.render(self)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 585, in render
    body,
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 158, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 299, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 702, in contribute_to_class
    super(ForeignObject, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name, virtual_only=virtual_only)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 308, in contribute_to_class
    lazy_related_operation(resolve_related_class, cls, self.remote_field.model, field=self)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 85, in lazy_related_operation
    return apps.lazy_model_operation(partial(function, **kwargs), *model_keys)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 83, in <genexpr>
    model_keys = (make_model_tuple(m) for m in models)
  File "/Users/reonard/.virtualenvs/django-ito/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/utils.py", line 14, in make_model_tuple
    app_label, model_name = model.split(".")
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I added a print statement for the model splitted and the output was:

```
auth.User
auth.Group_permissions
auth.User_groups
auth.User_user_permissions
app.ticketmgr.BasePriority
```

It appears that the "app.ticketmgr.BasePriority" has an extra "dot". Actually the app name is "ticketmgr" but put in an "app" folder for better managerment. May i know what should i do to make the migrations work? is there any extra settings should be done to support putting serveral apps in a "app" folder ?
Below is my app folder, there are 2 apps (comm, ticketmgr) in it.

```
|____app
| |______init__.py
| |____comm
| | |______init__.py
| | |____admin.py
| | |____apps.py
| | |____migrations
| | | |______init__.py
| | |____models.py
| | |____role_required.py
| | |____tests.py
| | |____views.py
| |____ticketmgr
| | |______init__.py
| | |____admin.py
| | |____apps.py
| | |____forms.py
| | |____migrations
| | | |____0001_initial.py
| | | |______init__.py
| | |____models.py
| | |____tests.py
| | |____views.py
```

Comment: Your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Hi , here is my INSTALLED_APPS:      INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'app.comm',
    'app.ticketmgr',
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing more is needed. Just add `"app.ticketmgr", "app.comm"` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: yes, i did so but not work. the problem looks caused by the `app_label, model_name = model.split(".")` splits `app.ticketmgr.BasePriority` into 3 values instead of 2. The project works when i used django default to create apps. but when i moved the apps into a "app" folder, it looks the model label `app.ticketmgr.BasePriority` has extra prefix `app.` and caused the error.

Comment: Hi, you are right, nothing more is needed. i solved this problem by delete all the migration files in the "migrations" folder for each app, and it works now. thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

BasePriority does not appear in your project directories. Maybe it's a model?

The installed app line should be:

```
app.ticketmgr
```

Since BasePriority does not exists, django gets 3 arguments instead of the 2 required for app_label,model_name. The "BasePriority" is the third argument, which excepts.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, BasePriority is one of the models defined in `comm.models`

Comment: It's in comm or ticktmgr? you printed it as app.ticktmgr

Comment: it was in ticketmgr at the beginning, but i moved it to comm later. after that i did a make migrations and got the error.  i resolved it by deleting all the old migration files and make migrations again. everything works fine now.